# Misplaced UI made with UI in hololens emulator

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface, hololens

I got a small problem and I can’t really find the source of it. I just created a Canvas and put a Panel in the top right corner. I got it to the right scale at 3: for the Hololens and loaded it up in the Holoemulator. The problem is that even though the panel is supposed to be in the corner, it is placed almost in the middle of the screen in the end. 
Is there anything I can do to fix this or is there something I am missing?

If I need to provide more information then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you double-check the [Render mode] of your Canvas? Is it set as World Space? In this render mode, the Canvas will behave as any other 3D object and will render in front of or behind other objects in the scene based on 3D placement in the scene. You need to adjust the position of the canvas from the perspective of the camera.

However, according to your post, it seems that you want to place UI elements on the screen rendered on top of the scene. If so, You should turn the [Render mode]  to [Screen Space - Camera]. More information please see: [Canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html)